# Tangent line of $y=A(x)$ at $x=\pi / 2$, where $A(x)$ is an integral function

Tags: calculus, integration

> Given the function $A$ defined by: 
>   $$A(x) = \int^x_{\pi/x}\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt$$
>   Find the equation of the tangent line of $y=A(x)$ at
>   $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

please try to explain in detail

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tangent to the graph of $A$ at $(x_0,A(x_0))$: $y=A(x_0)+A'(x_0)(x-x_0)$. So you just have to find the derivative of $A$. That is essentially the FTC, if you cut the integral in two pieces, plus the chain rule. The computation of $A(\pi/2)$ is not that obvious, on the other hand.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find a tangent line, and that involves finding the slope (derivative).  So, let's find $A'(x)$.

We can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC), which gives the result:

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)dt  = f(x)\tag{1}$$

So, we need to break your $A(x)$ into a form that matches $(1)$.  Basically, we want a constant in the lower limit of integration, and a function of $x$ to be in the upper limit of integration.  So, we have:

$$\begin{align}
A(x) &= \int^x_{\pi/x}\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt\\
 &= \int^a_{\pi/x}\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt + \int^x_a\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt \\
 &= -\int_a^{\pi/x}\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt + \int^x_a\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt \\
\end{align}$$

Now, we can apply the FTC to this to find $A'(x)$:
$$\begin{align}A'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[-\int_a^{\pi/x}\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt\right] + \frac{d}{dx}\left[\int^x_a\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt\right] \\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\left[-\int_a^{\pi/x}\frac{\sin t}{t} \,dt\right] + \left[\frac{\sin x}{x} \right]\\
&= \underbrace{\left[\frac{\sin \left(\pi/x\right)}{\pi/x}\cdot\frac{\pi}{x^2}\right]}_\text{don't forget chain rule!} + \left[\frac{\sin x}{x} \right]\\\\
&= \left[\frac{\sin \left(\pi/x\right)}{x}\right] + \left[\frac{\sin x}{x} \right]\\
&= \frac{\sin(\pi/x) + \sin x}{x} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Now, just use $(2)$ with julien's formula from the comments above, and you're basically done.  Leave a comment if you have questions.

Comment: hi thank you very much for the help. however the lower bound of the integral is  pi/2 not pi/x

Comment: @rrodrigorn0 My pleasure.  Since you're somewhat new to Math.SE, I thought I'd let you know about the "accept" feature.  If you believe my response has sufficiently answered your question, you can "accept" it by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.  This gives the answerer +15 reputation, and yourself +2 reputation.